# Adding margin around button components in Material UI

Tags: css, material-ui

I have a centered Toolbar in Material UI that has 3 components.  Each component is a button.  I want to add a margin around each button.   I tried adding the {mt} option to the component button as below, but nothing changed.  I've been experimenting with makeStyles, but haven't figured it out.

```
<Box display="flex">
  <Box m="auto">
    <Toolbar>
      <SeasonComponent>
      <WeekComponent>
      <GameComponent>
    </Toolbar>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

Season component:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Button 
      variant="outlined" 
      color="primary" 
      onClick={handleClickOpen}
      mt={2}
    >
      Button text 
    </Button>
</div>
```

Here is a picture of the buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap buttons in a horizontal `<Stack>`:

```
    <Toolbar>
      <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
        <SeasonComponent>
        <WeekComponent>
        <GameComponent>
      </Stack>
    </Toolbar>
```

Here's a simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicbuttons-material-demo-forked-0gpgz?file=/demo.js:234-269

Comment: This looks to be the right solution.  
It wants me to add the stack module
I tried both "import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack'"
and "import Stack from '@material-ui/core/Stack'" but neither worked (Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Stack')
my package.json says I am running
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",

Comment: The `<Stack>` component is not available in version 4. You may consider upgrading to v 5 (now known as **@mui/material**) not only because of this but also because of what they say: "All ongoing work has moved to v5. The development of v4 is limited to important bug fixes, security patches and easing the upgrade path to v5."

Comment: Thanks I will upgrade.  I wonder if there was a way to do this in v4.

Comment: Probably there was, but I like `<Stack>` . It is a very common concept in modern UIs, e.g. Qt or SwiftUI. I'm glad they have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than upgrade my repo to version 5 right now, I just added an invisible button between the buttons.  Not a perfect solution, but it solved the problem in the short term.

```
// SpacerButton.js
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const style = {
   minWidth: 1
}

export default function SpacerButton(props) { 
  return (
    <Button variant="text" style={style}>
      
    </Button>
  );
}
```